# What is the general/typical order of usage of UML diagrams during development?

Tags: uml

I want to know the order of UML diagrams. I need to know when I develop new software which UML diagram to use first and which second (and so on) thanks.

Comment: A related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229243/how-to-streamline-the-process-of-design-a-software-system

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not defined in the UML standard. UML is a notation not a software development method. You need to choose first a development method that uses the UML notation and then the method will tell you in what order you should define the different UML diagrams.

Comment: +1.  Irrespective of method however, it's very unlikely you'd create diagrams sequentially.  They tend to evolve in parallel.  For example, a Use Case model (possibly with some sequence diagrams/activity diagrams for selected UCs) in parallel with Domain Class Diagram.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, it looks like you really should start at the basics of what UML diagrams do before you start into how to use them.  Otherwise, you are going to find that you are in a mess.  Here is a good starting point:
http://www.agilemodeling.com/essays/umlDiagrams.htm

Comment: To get a basic idea of the UML notation, this page about the Best UML cheat sheets and reference guides can also be helpful:  http://modeling-languages.com/content/best-uml-cheat-sheets-and-reference-guides

Answer (score 0):

I would say if you are a beginner then start with a usecase diagram to capture requirements then create class diagrams in order show the static architecture.
You don't really need other diagrams.